# Returning a multipart polygon back to singlepart after editing

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Feature "A" had two polygons that would show up together as one record but after editing it turned into two separate records. I would like to get them back together so they are identified together and have one single record. What can I do to make that happen?

[image: This is before editing when they were one record]

[image: This is after editing, they now show up as two separate records]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your table is editable and the two polygons are selected then choose merge from the editor menu drop down